# Grails using submittoremote and onsuccess

Tags: javascript, grails, submit

I can't make my onSuccess event works... I try to use the data rendered by the controller but it doesn't work.

**My gsp code:**

```
<g:submitToRemote name="supprimerUsr" url="[controller:'user',action:'preSupprimerUser']" class="submit" 
    value="${g.message(code: 'liste.user.bouton.supprimer.label')}" update="messageInfoErro" onSuccess="confirmerSupprUser(data);"/>
```

Here is the method in my controller "preSupprimerUser":

```
def preSupprimerUser () {
    ...
    render(status: 200, text: 'haha')
    ...
}
```

Javascript method "confirmerSupprUser":

```
function confirmerSupprUser(data) {
    alert('confirm normal');
    alert(data.text + 'haha '+ data.status);
}
```

Whatever I try it doesn't work, I would like to have the text I render in the controller, but it prints "undefined".

How can I make this work ? Didn't find many documentation about it.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a typo: `update="messageInfoErro"`. Is it supposed to have an 'r' on the end of messageInfoErro?

Comment: Did you try `render [status: '200', text: 'haha'] as JSON` and then parse the returned json in your js function?

Comment: The answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113416/grails-remote-form-multiple-submits-with-javascript#answer-3114452) could solve the issue